# Ansible Dynamic Role execution

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Currently I have built out a huge playbook that has way too much in it to be organized.  I'm now breaking these tasks out into roles!  That said, I'm having some issues with calling these roles in a nice way.

For a basic understanding I have some pre_tasks that are being done which are creating variables based on installers that are found in a certain directory.  For now you can assume that `installer_types` is just Nuke & Houdini.

Here are the pre_tasks:

```
  pre_tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: "Select Installer {{ item|basename }} [y/n]"
      register: selected_installers
      loop: "{{ installer_types }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item|basename }}"

    - name: Register all files
      find:
        paths: "{{ installer_path }}"
        patterns: '*.pkg,*.dmg'
        file_type: file
      register: installers

    - name: Register Installers Selected
      set_fact:
        "{{ item.item|basename|lower }}_installers": "{{ installers.files|map(attribute='path')|map('basename')|list|select('search', (item.item|basename), ignorecase=True) }}"
      loop: "{{ selected_installers.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item|basename }}"
      when: item.user_input == 'y' and
            item.item == ( item.item|basename )
```

After this I am calling roles based upon what was selected "y" to initially for the installer prompt.

Tasks:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Run Houdini Install
      include_role:
        name: houdini
      loop: "{{ selected_installers.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item|basename }}"
      when: item.user_input == 'y' and
            item.item == "Houdini"

    - name: Run Nuke Install
      include_role:
        name: nuke
      loop: "{{ selected_installers.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item|basename }}"
      when: item.user_input == 'y' and
            item.item == "Nuke"
```

I can do this, no problem, but it will be quite a large list of installers in the end and would rather have this executed on a dynamic basis, rather than specifying each installer manually.

I'm not sure how to accomplish that with `include_role` and a loop.

Comment: It looks like you could have a single task that loops over `selected_installers.results` and set the `name:` argument of `include_role` to `{{ item.item|lower }}`

Comment: Incidentally, it's not clear why you're setting the `label` to `item.item|basename`; based on your `when` condition, you expect `item.item` to be a single word with no directory separators.

Comment: That did it! I'm not sure why I am labeling the loop_control either to be honest.  item.item|basename still shows the full installer name

Answer (score 0):

This works best for my usecase. Thanks to @larsks

```
    - name: Run Install roles
      include_role:
        name: "{{ item.item|lower }}"
      loop: "{{ selected_installers.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item|basename }}"
      when: item.user_input == 'y' and
            item.item == ( item.item|basename)
```